# Javascript function not fired on video timeupdate

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Currently working on a page containing a video that has to be paused at certain points (like chapters). So I made a function that will stop the video when it hits the next "time marker" which looks like this:

```js
function vidPause(nextMarker){
  var timeMarker = nextMarker;

  if(videoPlayer.currentTime >= timeMarker) {
    videoPlayer.pause();
    videoPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate', vidPause());
  }
};
```

And I'm trying to fire it this way:

```js
videoPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', vidPause(nextMarker));
```

But it only seems to fire when the video is loaded. Nothing happens when the video is playing (tested by using a `console.log(videoPlayer.currentTime);` inside the vidPause function).

Note: I need the function to be called that way so that I can remove the event listener when it hits the time marker, that way it won't stop when the user wants to play the video from that point on.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The function is being called once in the addEventListener line, but that's not actually passing it as a callback.

Try this:

```
function videoUpdate(e) {
  vidPause(nextMarker, videoPlayer.currentTime;); // Now call your function
}

function vidPause(nextMarker, timeStamp){
  var timeMarker = nextMarker;

  if (timeStamp >= timeMarker) {
    videoPlayer.pause();
    videoPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate', videoUpdate);
  }
};

videoPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoUpdate); // Note no brackets, as it's passing a ref to the function rather than calling it
```

I don't know what the scope of `nextMarker` is, but you should be able to start console logging and find out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it out and it isn't working, it pauses the video at 1 second or so even though the nextMarker is set at another value. It doesn't seem like it removes the event listener neither. But I don't understand the purpose of the timeStamp var, could you explain it? Also, the scope of nextMarker is global, any function can access it as it's defined at the top of my general script.

Comment: OK, made a couple of changes - 1. event.timeStamp is not the right property to get the current play time of the video. 2. Tried moving videoUpdate definition to ensure it's defined when the closure for vidPause is created. That may or may not be the cause of the problem, but it's probably a different question tbh